# When does python decide if a name is local or a reference to a global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

Consider the following code:

```
def f():
    y = x + 1

x = 1
f()
```

This code runs fine. As I understand it, when the function is called, python searches for the name `x` first in the local scope, and since it doesn't find it, it searches the global scope, reads the value of `x` and execution of code continues from there. So far, so good.

But the following piece of code throws an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`:

```
def g():
    y = x + 1
    x = y

x = 1
g()
```

So my guess is that python decided that `x` inside the `g` definition is a local variable. But when does this decision happen?

I guess it doesn't happen during code execution (when `g` is called in the last line). Because then python would read the first line inside the definition of `g` and interpret it like it happens in `f`, as a reference to the global variable `x`. Then it would read the second line in the definition of `g`, and it would create a local variable `x`. That would mean that inside the definition of g, the same name `x` would mean global and local at different lines, which would be a nightmare!

I'm wondering if the decision to bind `x` to the local namespace is taken while the `def` statement is parsed. What confuses me though is that the error is thrown only when the function is called (so during execution) and not after the `def` statement, when the function definition has been parsed.

Comment: Local variables are marked as such during compilation. What actually changes is the op-code in the compiled bytecode, but the error wont' actually occur until the code runs.